# Generated pdf using Flying Saucer and Itext PdfReader Exception: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I got the following Exception when I try to create and instance of PdfReader from a pdf file generated using flying saucer

Exception:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.
```

instance creation:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(new File(filesList.get(0)).getAbsolutePath());
```

seems the flying saucer does not generate a valid pdf that starts with %PDF,
can you help me

flying saucer code

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
renderer.finishPDF();
os.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's correct to close the `os` _before_ calling `renderer.finishPDF()`?

Comment: @mkl sorry its before,, missed it while copying it